# Understanding const pointer to const reference

Tags: c++

below is a code snippet i don't quite understand.
See the two lines with comment.
Happy for every explanation or reference to a side where i can find an explanation.
I don't quite understand whats going on and what is wrong at out = *command;

```
#include <variant>

struct Buffer
{
            struct StructA
            {
                int X = 10;
            };
            struct StructB
            {
                int X = 20;
            };

            std::variant<StructA, StructB> Data = StructA{};

            template <typename T>
            bool GetCommand(T& out)
            {
                T* command = std::get_if<T>(&Data);
                if (command != nullptr)
                {
                    out = *command;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            template <typename T>
            bool GetCommand(const T& out) const
            {
                const T* command = std::get_if<T>(&Data);
                if (command != nullptr)
                {
                    out = *command;     // don't understand
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
};

void dummy(const Buffer& buffer)
{
    Buffer::StructB tmpStruct;

    auto tmpBuffer = buffer;
    tmpBuffer.GetCommand<Buffer::StructB>(tmpStruct);

    buffer.GetCommand<Buffer::StructB>(tmpStruct); // don't compile
}

int main()
{
    Buffer buffer;
    dummy(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Hoping for a code explanation.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't assign to a `const&`. Somebody tried to be overly const-correct, to the point where they stop being correct at all. You only need one overload: `bool GetCommand(T& out) const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
bool GetCommand(const T& out) const
{
    const T* command = std::get_if<T>(&Data);
    if (command != nullptr)
    {
         out = *command;     // don't understand
```

`out` is a reference to a `const` object of type `T`. `out` refers to an object that can't be modified. When you try to call the assignment operator `=` on it, you try to modify `out`. So the compiler disallows it.